# Can't download files into website

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, download, silex

my website use Silex but it is substantially the same for Symfony.

On local computer, I can download any files (pdf, jpg, etc...) from my website,
but once hosted into the Debian server, I can't download nothink.

I got always the same basic message:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

However, url is the good one, but somethink seems to disabled or forbid files access...

What it should be ?

Thanks for help

Comment: the apache configuration, probably. Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Check with your service provider.  Most web servers can be configured to only allow access to files of certain types.  You should be able to override this in your application's .htaccess file.